# relation between a drop-down list and two others drop-down lists

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with last part of my code. I have a relation between the table of chargernumero and chargermateriels  but I want in the same time a relation between chagernumero and chagerservices.

This is my code php for the last relation:

```
<?php
  $reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM materiels WHERE id_type_materiels=\''.$_GET['id_type_materiels'].'\' ');
  while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch()){ ?>
    <tr><td> <?php echo ($donnees['numero_serie'])?> </td></tr>
<?php } ?>
```

and when I add in `$reponse id_serv=\''.$_GET['id_serv'].'\'`  that doesn't work

this is my js:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      function chargerEtablissement() {
        $.get("etabl.php", function(rep) {
          $("#divetab").html(rep);
          $("#tab").change(function() {
            chargerDivisions($(this).val());
          });
        });
      }

      function chargerDivisions(idC) {
        $.get("div.php?id_etabfk=" + idC, function(rep) {
          $("#divdiv").html(rep);
          $("#diva").change(function() {
            chargerServices($(this).val());
          });
        });
      }

      function chargerServices(idC) {
        $.get("serv.php?id_divfk=" + idC, function(rep) {
          $("#divserv").html(rep);
          $("#servo").change(function() {
            chargerMateriels($(this).val());
          });
        });
      }

      function chargerMateriels(idC) {
        $.get("mater.php?id_serv=" + idC, function(rep) {
          $("#divmat").html(rep);
          $("#matto").change(function() {
            chargerNumero($(this).val());
          });
        });
      }

      function chargerNumero(idC) {
        $.get("numero.php?id_type_materiels=" + idC, function(rep) {
          $("#divser").html(rep);


        })
      }
```

Comment: Please complete the JS. If it is like that in your code it will fail as seen after I formatted it. I would move all functions outside the document.ready

Comment: It's worth noting you have a security hole (SQL injection) in your code.

Comment: thank you for everything